# fetch_add with acq_rel memory order

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-model, stdatomic

Consider an

```
std::atomic<int> x(0);
```

Let's suppose I have a function doing the following:

```
int x_old = x.fetch_add(1,std::memory_order_acq_rel);
```

Based on the [description for acquire release memory ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

> **memory_order_relaxed**  Relaxed operation: there are no synchronization or ordering constraints, only atomicity is required of this operation (see Relaxed ordering below)
>
> **memory_order_consume** A load operation with this memory order performs a consume operation on the affected memory location: no reads or writes in the current thread dependent on the value currently loaded can be reordered before this load. Writes to data-dependent variables in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread. On most platforms, this affects compiler optimizations only (see Release-Consume ordering below)
>
> **memory_order_acquire** A load operation with this memory order performs the acquire operation on the affected memory location: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load. All writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread (see Release-Acquire ordering below)
>
> **memory_order_release** A store operation with this memory order performs the release operation: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this store. All writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable (see Release-Acquire ordering below) and writes that carry a dependency into the atomic variable become visible in other threads that consume the same atomic (see Release-Consume ordering below).
>
> **memory_order_acq_rel** A read-modify-write operation with this memory order is both an acquire operation and a release operation. No memory reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before or after this store. All writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible before the modification and the modification is visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable.
>
> **memory_order_seq_cst** Any operation with this memory order is both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order (see Sequentially-consistent ordering below)

Is it possible for 2 distinct threads to receive the same `x_old` value of 0? Or are they guaranteed to execute in a manner that `x_old` is 0 for only one of them, and is 1 for the other.

If it is true that `x_old` could be 0 for both of them, does changing the memory ordering to `std::memory_order_seq_cst` guarantee uniqueness of `x_old`?

Comment: Memory ordering is not relevant. Two threads cannot possibly get the same value (assuming the expression is reached only once in each thread).

Comment: Why should memory ordering not matter ? Couldn't both threads get the same x_old under acq_rel because there is no read-read ordering guaranteed for a read-modify-write operation?

Comment: Ordering is simply not relevant here. The first two values returned from fetch_add will always be: 0 and 1, but there is no guarantee which thread gets which value. This is true regardless of which memory_order you choose.

Comment: In that case, what exactly is the difference between a seq_cst and acq_rel memory_ordering on a fetch_add operation?

Comment: Operation with seq_cst also prevents reordering of other acquire and release operations across it.

Comment: @2501 "_Operation with seq_cst also prevents reordering of other **acquire and release** operations_" why especially these?

Comment: @AdityaSihag "_what exactly is the difference between a seq_cst_" Comments are not for completely new Q.

Comment: @2501 "_Operation with seq_cst also prevents reordering of other acquire and release operations across it_" You can't reorder w/ acq-rel operations, in general.

Comment: "_`memory_order_seq_cst` Any operation with this memory order is both an acquire operation and a release operation_" It isn't precisely true. Any operation that wouldn't accept either mo_acquire or mo_release (because it either doesn't observe a value or doesn't modify a value) is not magically made an acquire or a release operation by virtue of being `memory_order_seq_cst`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible for 2 distinct threads to receive the same x_old value of 0?

It is not possible because the operation is *atomic*. It either happens in full, or not happen at all.

Ordering is concerned with preceding/following loads/stores and since you do not have any, ordering is irrelevant here. In other words, `x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);` has the same effect here.

On current x86 is it the same `lock xadd` instruction regardless of `memory_order`, `lock` prefix provides both atomicity and ordering. For `memory_order_relaxed` the ordering part of `lock` is unnecessary.

Comment: so x.exchange(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) is also atomic and ordering is irrelevant here ?

Comment: @DerekZhang That's what the answer says, you got it right.

Comment: Thanks! I have anther question.   thread A run x.store(1, std::memory_order_release) first,  then thread B run x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) .   x in thread B is not guaranteed to read  1 store by A.  If I use memory_order_seq_cst, it will guaranteed to read 1.   right?

Comment: @DerekZhang It is best to post another question as a question, rather than a comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926915/atomic-load-store-with-memory-order  Thank you !

Comment: "_For memory_order_relaxed the ordering part of lock is unnecessary._" The ordering is necessary for the lock operation to avoid deadlocks. You can't get anything cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Any operation that is performed on memory is done inside the processor. Even if it is an atomic operation, the processor will read, modify and write back the new value. If the operation fails (depending on implementation it may not be able to fail, but rather block), it repeats itself. If it succeeds, for the operation to be correct, the new value must be the immediately previous value, modified as requested and then stored. The value modified is returned to the user. There is no reason for the processor to read again from memory and return the value from a random time. If the value returned was not the immediately previous, the resulting operation would be incorrect.

You can test it using something like this:

```
long repeats = 1000000000;
long x = 0;
long sum = 0;
void *test_func(void*arg){
    long local_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats; ++i) {
        local_sum += atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&x, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    atomic_fetch_add(&sum, local_sum);
    return NULL;
}
```

If the result is the same as a sequential execution, then all works fine.

```
    long correct_res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats * no_threads; ++i) {
        correct_res = correct_res + i;
    }
```

And for the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

long repeats = 1000000000;
long x = 0;
long sum = 0;
void *test_func(void*arg){
    long local_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats; ++i) {
        local_sum += atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&x, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    atomic_fetch_add(&sum, local_sum);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    long correct_res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats * 2; ++i) {
        correct_res = correct_res + i;
    }
    pthread_t pthread[2];
    pthread_create(&pthread[0], NULL, test_func, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pthread[1], NULL, test_func, NULL);

    pthread_join(pthread[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(pthread[1], NULL);
    printf("correct res : %ld\n res : %ld\n", correct_res, sum);
    if(correct_res == sum)
        printf("Success.\n");
    else
        printf("Failure.\n");
    return 0;
}
```