# atomic load store with memory order

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, memory-model, stdatomic

Thread A runs `x.store(1, std::memory_order_release)` first, 
then thread B runs `x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`.
`x` in thread B is not guaranteed to read 1 stored by A.

If I use `memory_order_seq_cst`, will it be guaranteed to read 1?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between memory orderings with regards to load/store of one atomic variable. This is because *`std::memory_order` specifies how memory accesses, including regular, non-atomic memory accesses, are to be ordered around an atomic operation.*

Read [std::memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) for full details. In particular:

> All modifications to any particular atomic variable occur in a total order that is specific to this one atomic variable.

Comment: "_how regular, non-atomic memory accesses are to be ordered around an atomic operation_" Only non atomic operations?

Answer (score 1):

> Thread A runs x.store(1, std::memory_order_release) first, then thread
>   B runs x.load(std::memory_order_acquire).

**How can you know that one thread did an operation after another?**

Essentially by testing a shared state? Like an atomic?

So the way to determine if the hypothesis is true would be... to test the conclusion: is "read 1 stored by A" true or false.

So the question reads exactly like a tautology (if x is 2+2, is x equal to 2+2) or a circularity.